# Why does copy assignment operator return *this?

Tags: c++

The copy assignment operator should just let the LHS equal the RHS.

Why does it return *this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This supports chained assignment:

```
a = b = c = 0;
```

This assigns 0 to each of a, b, and c.

Returning a (non-const) reference instead of a value supports things like:

```
(a = b) = 0;
```

Which is also allowed, though it's not very common.

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: It's probably a bigger deal that the reference return type avoids making a copy in the very common case where the return value is ignored.

Comment: or check the value of an assignment directly: `if( (f = fopen(...)) ){...}`.